# pyspark create a distinct list from a spark dataframe column and use in a spark sql where statement

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe df and a column name setp To create a list I wrote

```
setp_list=df.select ('setp').distinct().collect()
setp_array=[row.setp for row in setp_list]
setp_array= str(setp_array)[1:-1]
```

I wanted to use it in the spark.sql statement

```
df1=spark.sql(f"select * from table where setp in ({setp_array})").
```

I am not sure how to display the list to see how is was created but mainly I want it to include in the spark sql statement. It throws error at spark sql statement as invalid syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid collecting items from one table and use it in the query of another table. Use a `JOIN` to write relational queries.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')

df1 = spark.sql("select * from table semi join df using(setp)")
```

Comment: edited to use a more conservative tone... sorry for being too emotional while writing the post! @mazaneicha

Comment: @mck Oh cool did not realize that I could create a temp table and could use in spark sql. Got error while using semi join so used a subquery instead